# Autosize UI CollectionView to it's content

Tags: ios, xcode, uipopovercontroller, uicollectionview, autosize

I am using a UICollectionView with fixed size CollectionViewCells. I display this CollectionView in a popOver with an UIPopoverController.

My goal is that the popOver automatically resize to the CollectionView's content. So if I only have 4 cells, than it should be small. And if I have more cells, it should be bigger. I want to avoid the empty space left in the popOver.

So I don't want a fixed popOver size, but a variable one depending on the number of cells in the CollectionView.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a hard time figuring this out myself but just got it finally. You have to access your Collection View's **collectionViewLayout** property and then use the **collectionViewContentSize** method to get the size of your content.  You can then use those to resize your Collection View by setting it's frame.

```
CGRect rectangle;
rectangle = _collectionView.frame;
rectangle.size = [_collectionView.collectionViewLayout collectionViewContentSize];
_collectionView.frame = rectangle;
```

Now that your collection view is sized to it's content, you can set the popOver's size based on the collection view size. It may look something like this.

```
popOver.frame = _collectionView.frame;
```

or

```
[popOver sizeToFit];
```

Comment: Works for iOS 7, still broken in iOS 8